# How to remove custom required telephone field in customer account information?

Tags: magento-1.9, admin, customer-account

I am trying to remove the Telephone custom field in customer account information.
I am unsure how it loads the fields and how to remove a required option and field.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can do that directly from database. Open **eav_attribute** table and set value in **'is_required'** column from '1' to '0'.

Comment: i am trying this but its not worked

Comment: it should work, have you tried after cleaning cache?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this ...

```
$installer = Mage::getModel('customer/entity_setup', 'core_setup');
$installer->startSetup();
$installer->updateAttribute('customer_address','telephone', 'is_required', 0);
$installer->endSetup();
```

If its not enough please check this: [up to date guide to remove telephone required field from checkout](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/9740/up-to-date-guide-to-remove-telephone-required-field-from-checkout)